# Put View inside ViewPager below TabLayout

Tags: android, android-viewpager, android-tablayout

I'm looking for a way to put a `view` in my `ViewPager` below the `TabBar`.
I don't want it to be inside each `fragment`, because obiouvsly it would scroll every time I change the current fragment; I need that view to be fixed there without animations.

**This is what I have now putting the `View` inside my `TabLayout` [code + img]**

[image]

```
    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/mViewPager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/mTabLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:tabBackground="@color/colorPrimary"
            app:tabGravity="fill"
            app:tabMode="fixed"
            app:tabSelectedTextColor="@color/colorAccent"
            app:tabTextColor="@color/white">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="end"
                android:background="@drawable/background_accent_fading"
                android:paddingBottom="5dp"
                android:paddingEnd="5dp"
                android:paddingTop="5dp"
                android:text="RIPASSO"
                android:textAlignment="textEnd"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

        </android.support.design.widget.TabLayout>
    </android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>
```

**This, instead, is what I'm looking for**

As you can see, `RIPASSO` is below my tabs, but it is fixed there.

Is there a way of obtaining it? I didn' find anything

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your TabLayout mustn't be a child of your ViewPager.

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">
            <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
                android:id="@+id/tabs"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?android:actionBarSize"
                style="@style/AppTabLayout"
                app:tabTextAppearance="@style/AppTabTextAppearance"
                app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
                app:tabMode="fixed"
                app:tabGravity="fill"/>
            <!--here put your view, the one you want to appear in all pages.-->
        </LinearLayout>
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/popup_holder"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
            android:id="@+id/viewpager"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
            android:background="@android:color/white"/>
    </FrameLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: this works! thanks a lot, I misused it all the time :D

Answer (score 0):

you can use the default android tabs, follow this : 
Right click on app > New > Activity > Tabbed Activity.
and it will create everything for you.
if you want to change the color of the background color - underline color or text color.
you can do it in the XML or user

```
TabLayout tabLayout = binding.tabs;
    tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(mViewPager);
    tabLayout.setTabTextColors(getResources().getColor(R.color.white), getResources().getColor(R.color.white));
```